# no puedo iniciar sesion de mi login por mas que los datos sean correctos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo mi formulario de login,
los campos de usuario y contraseña no reconocen, por mas que sean correctos,
me funciona sin el hash,
pero cuando lo pongo el hash, no me funciona.
cuando quiero iniciar sesion, me sale un mensaje diciendo, datos erroneos (yo puse eso, por si los datos son erroneos)

```
**ESTE ES EL checklogin.php **
    <?php 
include "config.php";
include "Database.php";
 ?>
 <?php 
    $db = new Database();
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        

    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['pass']);
         if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){ // si mis campos estan vacios
          header('Location:../index.php?msg='.urlencode('Debe llenar los campos'));
         }else {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE user='$user'";
            $result = $db->select($query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    /*FUNCION PARA DESCENCRIPTAR */
                    if(password_verify($pass, $row["password"])){
                        /*para crear sesiones*/
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['u_usuario'] = $row["user"];
                        $_SESSION['u_contrasenia'] = $row["password"];
                        $login = $db->signIn($query);   
                    }
                    else{
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=si");//echo "mala sesion";
                    }
                }
            }else{  header("Location: ../index.php?error=si");/*echo "mala sesion";*/}
         }  header("Location: ../index.php?error=si");
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: tu campo "user" y "password" en tu tabla  "tbl_login" esta declarado como varchar(255)? o de que forma has declarado tus atributos de tu tabla? posiblemente no obtenga el cifrado completo,Seri bueno que compartas como has realizado el encriptado con hash.

Comment: eliminaste el usuario que ya tenias encriptado? debes regustrar un nuevo usuario  y probarlo con el varchar (255)

Comment: @Santiago me funciono, muchas gracias... Solo era eso

Comment: que bueno, Saludos